# C#: Роли в приложении

Tags: c#, windows

Добрый день.

Есть обычное оконное приложение, на которой имеются три вкладки : две из которых нужно видеть **пользователю**, а третью - **администратор**. Было бы логично, реализовывая роли в этом приложении, добавить в БД таблицу "Роли", "Пользователи" и на этом завязать это дело.

**Меня вот что интересует - есть ли какие-то стандартные средства (студии, виндовс) которыми можно добавить роли в приложение ?** (если такое, конечно, вообще существует.) Например, разрабатывая веб-сайт, при его конфигурации можно указать пользователи, и привязать к ним роли.  Существует ли нечто подобное для оконных приложений?

Спасибо.

Comment: База данных? Зачем? А булевы переменные уже вышли из моды[?](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition)

Comment: @VladD, можно так сделать, ног тогда придется как-то идентифицировать клиента. Если их всего два - то программа должна как-то понять, что это за пользователь.

Comment: Он имел в виду `bool IsAdmin` у пользователя, а не не использовать bool в качестве пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет.

Длинный вариант:

В Web роли это, прежде всего, ограничение на операции доступа к данным. Т.к. сами операции полностью контролируются кодом сайта, и доступа к данным в обход сайта нет - жесткое разделение на роли имеет смысл. Т.е. ситуация в web:

- У кода есть полный доступ к данным
- У пользователя нет прямого доступа к данным (он не может залезть в базу, никак).
- Только код сайта определяет что можно пользователю, а что нельзя, на основе роли пользователя.

Отключение части интерфейса при этом - вторично, это просто следствие возможности запретить какую-то операцию.

В WinForms (по крайней мере у вас) - у пользователя есть доступ к данным в обход приложения - он может вытащить connection string. Всегда.

- У кода есть полный доступ к данным
- У пользователя есть точно такой же полный доступ к данным, он использует приложение только для собственного удобства (таблицы прямо в базе править неудобно).
- Код приложения определяет, показывать ли пользователю куски интерфейса.

Т.е. разделение **прав доступа** на уровне приложения на основе ролей можно сделать только в Web. Именно оно в .NET и реализовано. И вся инфраструктура для ролей создана именно для поддержки разграничения прав. А изменение интерфейса на основе ролей не реализовано ни в web, ни в win.

Comment: Но ограничения могут быть наложены и на пользователя на уровне базы. Например, если пользователь подключается к базе через windows autentification, то для каждого можно настроить нужные ему права. И было бы странно, если бы интерфейс программы на эти изменения никак не реагировал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Инфраструктура ролей в web существует прежде всего для реализации механизма проверки прав, а не для отображения принятых решений по правам на UI. В случае windows auth эта инфраструктура есть, и она полностью внешняя по отношению к коду приложения. В win auth "добавить роли в приложение" в смысле "сделать разделение прав доступа кодом приложения" нельзя. Максимум - подогнать интерфейс под внешнее решение "можно/нельзя". А готовой инфраструктуры в .NET для прятанья частей приложения нет ни в web, ни в win (по крайней мере в каком-то сложном виде).

Comment: Я ничего не говорил про готовую инфраструктуру. Я сказал только, что  физическое разделение пользователей десктопного приложения возможно. И если интерфейс не отвечает фактическим ограничениям, то это плохой интерфейс.

Comment: @Qwertiy естественно, возможно. Но к ролям и пользователям в виде "таблицы ролей" и к средствам студии для с ними, которые ищет TC, это не имеет отношения.